# How should I use a footnote reference inside a figure?

Tags: paper-submission, writing-style, formatting

I am using a figure in my paper, wherein one of the components of the figure, I need to refer to a method that I have described in a section with an equation.

I want to use a small footnote reference in the figure, in the footnote, I will describe that I have explained the method in section **X** with the equation **Y**.

What should be the standard way to do it? Using square brackets (ex. [1]) can be confused with the reference section, so how to place it so it's not confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you add your remarks to the figure caption. Its purpuse is to help making the figure understandable. A footnote reference in the figure can easily be overlooked, so I would not recommend it.

Comment: This approach also has the advantage that there is no need to update the figure if the section or equation numbering changes, or if the figure is reused in another document.